# Is it possible to configure TortoiseGit master only hook?

Tags: git, hook, tortoisegit

Is it possible to  configure tortoise git **master only** hook?
Is there a way to automate skipping?

My task is to

- to skip pre-commit hook when I am in branch
- use pre-commit hook while in master (same working dir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following at the top of your hook's script:

```
if [ `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` != "master" ]
  then
  exit 0
fi
```

This will cause the hook to only run on master.

Comment: thanks , it worked

`FOR /f  %%a IN ('git symbolic-ref --short HEAD') DO (  IF %%a EQU master ({RUN  CODE}))`

Answer (score 0):

To answer in a word : yes you can.
To achieve this you have to modify your hook accordingly.

Please find below steps for achieving this.

1. Within your hook, first check which branch you are on (use GIT branch command).
2. take the output of this command into bash variable and check if its Master.
3. if its master then only run your logic or else simply return the script with exit0;

Note: exit 0 is used to finish your script normally, if you want your script to stop then use exit 1 as status.